# Google Wallet use case

Tags: payment-gateway

I sell small game servers on a website and used to be able to have customers pay through Google Checkout. Since that has been replaced with Google Wallet, I've been trying to set it up. However, I think I have to "apply" to use the buttons now and the requirements are:

```
-Have the ability to process their own payments with a qualified payment processor
-Maintain PCI compliance
-Sell physical goods online or through their Android native application, and do not sell any digital goods through their Android native application
```

Since I don't meet any of these requirements, is it true that I cannot use any Google service as a payment method? Am I doing this wrong?

For reference, I'm getting them from this site: https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/ then click "sign up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements to use Google Wallet Instant Buy are as follows:-

- Instant Buy is currently only available to U.S. buyers for transactions in USD currency. Do not display the Buy with Google button for non-US transactions.
- There is an $1800 transaction limit with Instant Buy. For items beyond this limit, use alternative payment methods.
- Review the detailed Content policies to make sure your specific goods or services are supported.
- If you exclusively sell digital goods such as movies or games, use Google Play In-app Billing for Android or the Digital Goods API instead of Instant Buy.
- You must have your own payment processor for processing credit card payments.

You will need to sign up for a payment provider in order to accept card payments otherwise you will not be able to use Google Wallet. Surely this is something you can do so that you can then use GWIB?

Comment: I'm new to this. What does sign up for a payment provider entail?

Comment: It means opening a merchant account with a provider so that you can install their payment gateway on your website in order to take payments. You may wish to read [this](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/the-big-list-of-payment-gateways-for-the-global-merchant/) which includes a lot of advice, information and lists of providers.